# Vim - how to join lines using matching pattern

Tags: regex, join, vim, flat-file

I have a txt file that contains contact info for businesses. Currently, each line contains a different piece of data for the business. I'm attempting to construct a pipe-delimited file with all the info for each business on a single line. The catch is that there are a different number of lines for each business. So the file looks like this:

```
Awesome Company Inc|
Joe Smith, Owner|
Jack Smith, Manager|
Phone: (555)456-2349|
Fax: (555)456-9304|
Website: www.awesomecompanyinc.com [HYPERLINK: http://www.awesomecompanyinc.com]|
  * Really Cool Company|
  * Line of business: Awesomesauce|
Killer Products LLC|
Jack Black, Prop|
Phone: (555)234-4321|
Fax: (555)912-1234|
1234 Killer Street, 1st Floor|
Houston, TX 77081|
  * Apparel for the classy assassin|
  * Fearful Sunglasses|
  * Member of the National Guild of Killers since 2001|
  * Line of business: Fuhgettaboutit|
```

etc.

So I can use `:g/<pattern>/j` to join lines within a pattern but I'm having trouble working out what the pattern should be. In the example above, lines 1-9 need to joined, and then lines 10-19.

The key is the lines that begin with 2 spaces and an asterisk:

```
  * Line of business
```

The pattern should basically say: "Starting with the first line beginning with a letter, join all lines until the first line after the last line beginning with `\ \ \*\`, then repeat until the end of the file."

How would I write this? Should I maybe do it in two steps - i.e., is there a way to first join all the lines starting with letters, then all the lines starting with `\ \ \*\`, then join each resulting pair?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Starting with the first line beginning with a letter, join all lines until the first line after the last line beginning with `\ \ *\`, then repeat until the end of the file.*

You can actually translate that almost literally to Vimscript:

- *Starting with the first line beginning with a letter* is `/^\a/`
- *until the first line after the last line beginning with `*`* is `/^  \* .*\n\a`: find a line starting with the bullet (`^  \*`), match the rest of the line (`.*`), and assert that the next line isn't a bulleted one (`\n\a`)
- *then repeat until the end of the file.* is done via `:global`

Taken together:

```
:global/^\a/,/^  \* .*\n\a/join
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: nevermind, just realized that there are a bunch of settings that would have to be set for my solution to work. To make it work generally you would need

```
  for i in range(10)
      try
           v/business/join
      endtry
   endfor
```

And even that assumes that there isn't a business block that has more than 1024 lines. At that point you might as well use ranges